# Wifi won't work and computer won't shutdown

Tags: wireless-networking, shutdown

I play Sims 3 and recently, when I save and close, (it also happens even when I don't play Sims 3) my wifi just disconnects from my router, and the computer won't let me reset the wifi adapter by disabling it and re-enabling it. Also my computer won't shut down, meaning that I have to force it off. Can anyone help?

<strike>Edit: This only happens when I click `Quit` or `Save & Quit`, but if I save, then open the Task Manager and force it to close, this problem won't be present.</strike>

I use a Windows 7 64-bit desktop computer. Here are some hardware details:

- Graphics: Intel (R) G54/G43 Express Chipset (on-board)
- Wifi card: Ralink RT73 USB WLAN Card
- CPU: Pentuim (R) Dual-Core CPU E5700 @ 3.00 GHz x 2
- 8 GB RAM

If you need more details feel free to ask for them, and I will edit where necessary.

Comment: Can you at least tell me why you are hitting the down arrow?

Comment: I didn't vote you down but I can guess why the downvotes. Your question is very sparse on specific details. It would be very hard for someone to answer your question in any definite way as it stands. See the [FAQ](http://superuser.com/faq#dontask) for more info about what and how to ask a question.

Comment: Hi Mark! You're missing very important details. At least mentioning your operating system and giving us your hardware specifics would definitely improve your question. Maybe you could describe the problem with regard to when exactly it happens (e.g. only when you play Sims 3? Every time you play Sims 3? etc).

Comment: there's a well-known document that's worth researching: http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of information missing here, but you might try it hardwired in to the router and see if the issue persists or if it is resolved. Especially if you have a wifi adapter and an ethernet adapter, it will help narrow it down.

Comment: The problem is that the router is on the other side of the house... But we will try... Any other information I failed to mention?